# NuxtJS Head Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Nuxt.js pushes a [strange head configuration syntax](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head/) as the "way" to set elements in the head. Is there anyway to do this in Nuxt using  HTML or Vue components? It feels very strange for this to be part of a `nuxt.config.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can add a `head` method in every component.

> You can also use `head` as a function in your components to access the component data through `this` ([read more](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-head)).

Here is the example from the [read more](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-head) page :

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'Hello World!'
    }
  },
  head () {
    return {
      title: this.title,
      meta: [
        // hid is used as unique identifier. Do not use `vmid` for it as it will not work
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'My custom description' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```